# Downloand HTML page from the url with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I didn´t find any way on the internet.
Is it possible to download full HTML page file from url address using BeautifulSoup or something like that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://example.com')

with open('example.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

The above block won't render anything with Javascript. If you need Javascript rendered content then you can use the `requests-html` library (`pip install requests-html`):

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('http://example.com')

with open('example.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Great, it works! Thanks!
But, one problem, when I downloand the page it says that there is JavaScript disabled, but when I downloand it normally from the browser (CTRL+S), it works fine. Do you know, If I can fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html Only Python 3.6 is supported. Are you using Python 2?

Comment: No, I´m running Python 3.6.4